# php foreach loop I am doing something wrong

Tags: php, yii2

Like for example, I have the following code

```
if ($result == 1) {
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        $request_date = $record['date'];
        $request_starttime = $record['start_time'];
        echo $request_date . " " . $request_starttime;
    }
    throw new UserException("Unfortunately, this slot is already booked,please check another slot");
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Here exception is showing fine, but the echo code before that in the block is not displaying on the page.

How I can achieve this?

The result of `print_r($slots)`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-12-12 12:45:00
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-12-12 12:45:00
    [1] => 2018-12-12 13:00:00
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-12-12 12:45:00
    [1] => 2018-12-12 13:00:00
    [2] => 2018-12-12 13:15:00
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-12-12 12:45:00
    [1] => 2018-12-12 13:00:00
    [2] => 2018-12-12 13:15:00
    [3] => 2018-12-12 13:30:00
)
```

I have added the `print_r($slots)` just before the `throw new userException` line.

The more detailed code block is like this:

```
foreach ($order_item as $key => $value) {
                $order = new OrderItem();
                $class_info = ClassDuration::find()->where(['id' => $value['id']])->one();

                $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($model->create_date));

                //$p_price = $value['price'];

                $order->cd_id = $value['id'];
                $order->user_id = $UserId;
                $order->location_id = $value['location_id'];
                $order->instructor_id = $value['instructor_id'];
                                $order->date = $value['date1'];
                $order->start_time = $value['starttime'];
                $order->end_time = date("h:i",strtotime($value['endtime']));

                //$order->price = $p_price * $value['q'];
                $order->order_id = $model->id;
                                $instructor=$value['instructor_id'];
                                $date=$value['date1'];
                                $starttime =$value['starttime'];


                                $query = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `order_item` WHERE `instructor_id`='$instructor' and `date` = '$date'  AND `start_time` = '$starttime'), 1, 0)");
                                $query1 = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM `order_item` WHERE exists(select * FROM dual where `instructor_id`='$instructor' and `date` = '$date'  AND `start_time` = '$starttime')");
              $records=$query1->queryAll();
              $result=$query->queryScalar();
              //var_dump($result);exit;

              if ($result == 1) {
              foreach ($records as $record) {
              $request_date = $record['date'];
              $request_starttime = $record['start_time'];
              $slots[] = $request_date . " " . $request_starttime;

              }
                                print_r($slots);
                                $userMessage = "Unfortunately, this slot is already booked,please check another slot." . implode("<br />", $slots);
                                //throw new UserException($userMessage);   
                                //echo $userMessage;

                                }else{

                //$order->save();
                                }
                // $grand_total = $grand_total + $order->price;
                $ttl_dis = $ttl_dis;

            }
```

Comment: the exception will appear each time after the `foreach()` that you have inside the condition `$result==1`, not sure what you are doing here. how do you determine that the slot is not available ? and no text other than the mentioned as the exception text will be displayed

Comment: Hi Omer, I have two sql queries one is, which returns all the matching records for the classes being booked if exists and the second is it just returns 1 or 0 if record exist or not.

Comment: if `$result==1` that is confirmed by the sql query before that. so the execption and the foreach part to show which slots already booked after the time customer added to cart and before he actually places the order.

Comment: just out of curiosity why do you have 2 queries for the same thing , why not get the `sizeof()` the first query's result set, **which returns all the matching records for the classes being booked** to determine if the slot is booked, other than that, you have those slots that are already booked inside the `$records` if i am getting you correctly and you want to display those slots along with the exception ?

Comment: Assuming there are no style rules on your page that would prohibit the text from displaying, it stands to reason that `$records` is empty, if the `echo` isn't showing anything. To get a better reading of the problem, you'll probably want to substitute the `echo` for an `error_log()`, keeping the same string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to list the slots that are retrieved as already booked by another user inside `$records`, as the part of the text that you are showing in the exception, if that is correct then the exception will not allow you to show any other text except the one mentioned inside the exception message you should append the text with the exception message and then you can display it along with the message.

```
if ($result == 1) {
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        $request_date = $record['date'];
        $request_starttime = $record['start_time'];
        $slots[] = $request_date . " " . $request_starttime;
    }
    $userMessage = "Unfortunately, this slot is already booked,please check another slot." . implode("<br />", $slots);
    throw new UserException($userMessage);
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

**Update**

you should check for the slots before you save anything in the model and redirect to the view see the below code i added an extra function to `checkSlots()`

```
public function actionCheckout() {

    if( Yii::$app->user->isGuest ){
        return $this->redirect(['/site/login-popup']);
    }

    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $model = new Order();
    //$profile = UserProfile::findOne(24);//(['id' => 27])->all();//->where(['id'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->id])->one();
    $user = User::findOne(['id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
    $profile = UserProfile::findOne(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
    $billinginfo = UserBillingInfo::findOne(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
    $userchildren = UserChildren::findOne(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);
    $modelsKids = $user->kids;
    //var_dump($modelsKids);exit;
    //Customer::findOne(10);
    // var_dump($profile->zipcode);exit;
    $model->status = "unpaid";
    $model->first_name = Yii::$app->user->identity->first_name;
    $model->last_name = Yii::$app->user->identity->last_name;
    $model->mobile = Yii::$app->user->identity->phone;
    $model->email = Yii::$app->user->identity->email;
    $model->address = isset($profile->street1) ? $profile->street1 : '';
    $model->city = isset($profile->city) ? $profile->city : '';
    $model->state = isset($profile->state) ? $profile->state : '';
    $model->post_code = isset($profile->zipcode) ? $profile->zipcode : '';



    $pp = new PaypalPayment();

    $st = Yii::$app->getTable;
    $site_name = $st->settings('general', 'site_name');

    if( Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ){
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }

    //$order_item = \Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->getValue('order_item');
    $order_item = $session['value'];

    if( count($order_item) <= 0 ){
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $total = 0;

    for( $x = 0; $x < count($order_item); $x++ ){

        // $cart_p_p = $order_item[$x]['price'];
        // $total = $total + $cart_p_p * $order_item[$x]['q'];
    }

    if( Yii::$app->user->isGuest ){
        return $this->render('checkout', [
                    'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }


    $UserId = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;

    //check if all slots are available
    $allSlotsAvailable = $this->checkSlots($order_item);

    if( $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $allSlotsAvailable ){
        $user = User::findOne(['id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);

        $profile = UserProfile::findOne(['user_id' => $user]);
        if( !empty($UserProfile) ){
            $profile = UserProfile::findOne(['user_id' => $user]);
        } else{
            $profile = new UserProfile();
        }

        $model->order_number = date('ymdhis');

        $model->create_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $model->status = 1;
        $model->create_by = $UserId;
        // $model->order_amount = $total;
        //var_dump($_REQUEST);
        $user->phone = $_REQUEST['Order']['mobile'];
        $user->first_name = $_REQUEST['Order']['first_name'];
        $user->last_name = $_REQUEST['Order']['last_name'];
        $profile->user_id = $user->id;
        $profile->mobile = $_REQUEST['Order']['mobile'];
        $profile->street1 = $_REQUEST['Order']['address'];
        $profile->city = $_REQUEST['Order']['city'];
        $profile->state = $_REQUEST['Order']['state'];
        $profile->zipcode = $_REQUEST['Order']['post_code'];
        $profile->save(false);

        if( !empty($_REQUEST['Order']['kids']) ){
            $model->kids = serialize($_REQUEST['Order']['kids']);
        }
        $model->save();
        $user->save();

        $model->orderUpdate($model->id, 1, NULL);

        $grand_total = 0;
        $ttl_dis = 0;



        foreach( $order_item as $key => $value ){
            $order = new OrderItem();
            $class_info = ClassDuration::find()->where(['id' => $value['id']])->one();

            $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($model->create_date));

            //$p_price = $value['price'];

            $order->cd_id = $value['id'];
            $order->user_id = $UserId;
            $order->location_id = $value['location_id'];
            $order->instructor_id = $value['instructor_id'];
            $order->date = $value['date1'];
            $order->start_time = $value['starttime'];
            $order->end_time = date("h:i", strtotime($value['endtime']));

            //$order->price = $p_price * $value['q'];
            $order->order_id = $model->id;

            $order->save();

            // $grand_total = $grand_total + $order->price;
            $ttl_dis = $ttl_dis;
        }



        $model->order_amount = $grand_total;

        $model->save();


        $session->remove('date1');
        $session->remove('time1');

        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('orderPlaced');



        $link = '#';



        if( $model->payment_method == 'paypal' ){

            $new_array = $order_item;

            $pp->addMultipleItems($new_array);

            return $pp->getCheckoutForm($model->id);
        } elseif( $model->payment_method == 'invoice' ){

            $content = $this->renderPartial('_invoice', ['model' => $model]);
            //var_dump($content);
            $filename = 'web/customer-invoice/invoice' . $model->id . '.pdf';

            $pdf = new Pdf(['format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4]);
            $mpdf = $pdf->api;
            $stylesheet = file_get_contents('themes/common/css/print/invoice.css');
            $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
            $mpdf->WriteHtml($content);
            $mpdf->Output($filename, 'F');

            $from_email = $st->settings('email', 'from_email');
            $from_name = $st->settings('email', 'from_name');

            $user = User::findOne($UserId);

            $to = $user['email'];

            $email_template = $st->email_template(10);

            \Yii::$app->mailer->compose('template', ['id' => 10, 'user_id' => $UserId,
                        'email_template' => $email_template,
                        'model' => $model,
                        'link' => $link])
                    ->setFrom([$from_email => $from_name])
                    ->setTo($to)
                    ->setSubject($email_template['subject'] . ' ' . $site_name)
                    ->attach($filename)
                    ->send();
        } elseif( $model->payment_method == 'booking' ){
            $admin = User::find()->select('email')->where(['user_role' => 'admin'])->asArray()->all();
            $admin = ArrayHelper::getColumn($admin, 'email');


            $content = $this->renderPartial('_booking', ['model' => $model]);
            //  var_dump($content);
            $filename = 'web/customer-booking/booking' . $model->id . '.pdf';

            $pdf = new Pdf(['format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4]);
            $mpdf = $pdf->api;
            $stylesheet = file_get_contents('themes/common/css/print/invoice.css');
            $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
            $mpdf->WriteHtml($content);
            $mpdf->Output($filename, 'F');

            $from_email = $st->settings('email', 'from_email');
            $from_name = $st->settings('email', 'from_name');

            $user = User::findOne($UserId);
            $orderid = Order::find(['created_by' => $user->id])->select('id')->orderBy('create_date DESC')->one();
            $instructor_id = OrderItem::find()->select('instructor_id')->where(['order_id' => $orderid])->distinct();
            $Instructor = User::findOne($instructor_id);
            // var_dump($instructor_id);exit;
            // $admin = ArrayHelper::getColumn($admin, 'email');

            $to = $user['email'];
            $instructor_email = $Instructor['email'];
            $admin[] = $to;
            $admin[] = $instructor_email;
            //  $to .= $Instructor['email'];

            $email_template = $st->email_template(10);

            \Yii::$app->mailer->compose('template', ['id' => 10, 'user_id' => $UserId,
                        'email_template' => $email_template,
                        'model' => $model,
                        'link' => $link])
                    ->setFrom([$from_email => $from_name])
                    ->setTo($admin)
                    ->setSubject($email_template['subject'] . ' ' . $site_name)
                    ->attach($filename)
                    ->send();
        }

        //Yii::$app->response->cookies->remove('order_item');
        unset($session['value']);

        return $this->redirect(Yii::getAlias('@web') . '/order/view?id=' . $model->id);
        //return $this->redirect('result');
    } else{
        return $this->render('checkout', [
                    'model' => $model,
                        //  'modelsKids' => (empty($modelsKids)) ? [new UserChildren] : $modelsKids,
        ]);
    }
}

private function checkSlots($order_items) {
    $slots = [];
    foreach( $order_items as $item ){
        $instructor = $item['instructor_id'];
        $date = $item['date1'];
        $starttime = $item['starttime'];

        $query = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `order_item` WHERE `instructor_id`='$instructor' and `date` = '$date'  AND `start_time` = '$starttime'), 1, 0)");
        $result = $query->queryScalar();
        if( $result == 1 ){
            $slots[] = $date . " " . $starttime;
        }
    }

    if( sizeof($slots) ){
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', "Unfortunately, this slot is already booked,please check another slot<br />".implode("<br />", $slots));
        return false;
    } else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

in the function `checkSlots($order_items)` you will see that I have removed one of your queries

```
$query1 = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM `order_item` WHERE exists(select * FROM dual where `instructor_id`='$instructor' and `date` = '$date'  AND `start_time` = '$starttime')");
```

as its un-necessary to retrieve the records for the same `date` and `start_time` that you are querying with, and just use the result from the first query and add the date and start time to the `$slots` and once all records are checked and if there are any reserved slots the method returns false and the view will be displayed along with the flash message that will show all those slots that are reserved.

Comment: Hi Omer I don't know, but it is showing only the first slot in the exception block. but if I just echo `$userMessage` it shows all the message with some repetitions though.

Comment: @Joshi it works correctly for me and displays all the slots that are inside the `$slots` array , you might need to check the `UserException` that you are using i used simple `\Exception()`

Comment: i just checked and it works correctly with the `UserException` too

Comment: Hmm. what I am doing wrong then? strange. what else I must check Omer?

Comment: can you show the sample data that is inside the slots using `print_r($slots)` before throwing the `exception`? @Joshi

Comment: it looks like I have `foreach` within another `foreach` which is causing this issue.

Comment: you are adding multiple orders and inside that `foreach` you have another `foreach` that is iterating the booked slot and showing the exception and obviously once the exception is thrown if it is for the first order then the no more further orders will be processed or the loop wont continue you should change the logic and collect all the slots and use a flag to check if any or the orders were not added due to already booked slots and then display the exception. @Joshi

Comment: HI Omer I just noticed that if I am not using - `$slots[] = $request_date . " " . $request_starttime` and just using `$slots = $request_date . " " . $request_starttime;` the `print_r($slots);` is returning this string - `2018-12-12 12:45:002018-12-12 13:00:002018-12-12 13:15:002018-12-12 13:30:00` now we need to split those strings.

Comment: so the string contains all the 4 slots booked.

Comment: well try changing the `$slots = $request_date . " " . $request_starttime;` to `$slots. = $request_date . " " . $request_starttime."<br />";`

Comment: but i am still not sure what you are doing here, you should use the `transaction` block and rollback the transaction if the slot is already booked, in case you donot want any order to be added if any one of the slot is booked. @Joshi

Comment: are you trying to do the same as mentioned in the last comment? if any of the slots is booked while iterating on the `$orders` you dont want to add any of the orders in the database? **OR** you want to log the error and move on to the next record and add it if the slot is not booked?

Comment: It is showing nicely each on separate line. as for your last comment, No if any of the slot is booked, I don't want the order to be complete, but at the same time I am giving the user to remove the specifc slot and add another slot to the cart and checkout.

Comment: No Omer, it is working for `print_r` but while enabling the exception I am getting invalid argument passed and if take out the implode and keep $slots only. it is returning just 1st slot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184589/discussion-between-muhammad-omer-aslam-and-joshi).